# How do I can expand the Jiva Storage Volumes in OpenEBS?

Tags: kubernetes, openebs

I have created OpenEBS volume with 55GB initially which is mounted on my host. Now I need to expand it to 75GB. Is it possible to expand the same? If possible,Is there any impact for my application during the change?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jiva storage volume can be expanded. Detailed explanation in https://docs.openebs.io/docs/next/tasks_volumeprovisioning.html

Comment: Well, here is a better docs that show the procedure: https://openebs.io/docs/additional-info/kb